# SSIS 2016 / Visual Studio 2015 Deployment Issues

Tags: sql-server, deployment, ssis, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2016

I am running into an issue with SSIS project deployment using Visual Studio 2015 and SSIS 2016 [SSISDT March 2016 update] (SQL Server 2016 13.0.1300.275).

I am receiving the following error, when clicking deploy on the project or package:

[image]

> Field not found:
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Wizard.Common.Model.DeploymentModel.TargetServerVersion'.

I originally assumed it was due to the fact that the project was upgraded from a previous version of SSIS, so I created a new project altogether specifically for 2016, but received the same error.

The error doesn't appear to be coming from the SQL Server itself, instead from Visual Studio 2015 and the SQLDT.

I am hoping someone else may have encountered this issue and may have a suggestion on how to proceed.

**Folder capture after the build.**
[image: Here is a screen capture of the folder directory]
**Output of Build:**

> ------ Build started: Project: 340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration, Configuration: Development ------ Build started: SQL Server
>   Integration Services project: Incremental ... Starting project
>   consistency check ... Project consistency check completed. The project
>   is consistent. File 'C:\Users\kjackson\Documents\TFS Project
>   Repository\SSIS Projects
>   2016\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration\obj\Development\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration.dtproj'
>   get updated. 340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration ->
>   C:\Users\kjackson\Documents\TFS Project Repository\SSIS Projects
>   2016\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration\bin\Development\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration.ispac
>   Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Assuming "MyProject", there should be a `bin\Deployment\MyProject.ispac` file sitting under MyProject.dtproj. Further assuming default install paths `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\ISDeploymentWizard.exe /silent /SourcePath:"C:\dev\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Development\MyProject.ispac" /DestinationServer:"localhost" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB/MyProject/MyProject /ModelType:Project" the last parameter may have been factored out, it's ~9 months old as of writing this. That should fire off the deployment wizard - what error does it generate - same?

Comment: Hopefully, there is just a disconnect between the tool shipped with VS 2015 and the actual SQL Server deployment bits. You can also try firing up the SSMS 2015 and see if it can deploy the same ispac file and if not, what error does it generate.

Comment: @billinkc Thanks for the response...unfortunately neither of the projects I am attempting to deploy appear to have a bin\Deployment folder for the .ispac to reside. So perhaps that's my first issue...

Comment: Right click on the project and select Build. Assuming no errors, you'd end up with an ispac. Pop a screenshot of your project/solution if it's not creating an ispac. Your question specifies the Project Deployment Model so I'd expect this all to be working.

Comment: @billinkc Build\Rebuild ran with no errors but no .ispac was created.

Comment: I've include additional information in the main question. ie Screen captures and output messages.

Comment: It's there. Look at the last lines of the Output `bin\Development\340BHierarchyReDesign_Migration.ispac`

Comment: I see that but I'm still not able to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with SQL 2016 and Visual Studio 2015 with SSDT, as of RC1 and RC2. There are apparently assemblies in SSDT and 2016 RC1\RC2 that are mismatched at this time and as a result you are unable to debug or deploy anything from the Visual Studio 2015 environment.

The current suggested workaround from Microsoft is to either uninstall SSDT and SQL 2016 RC1\RC2 from the computer running Visual Studio 2015 and reinstall the SSDT only. Or install an early release of the SSDT which limits you from using the 2016 features. This maybe resolved in RC3.